# Retrieve Blazor page route parameters in child component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to retrieve the page's URI parameters from within a child component.

Scenario: My Layout hosts a Navigation menu. Inside the links of these items I need to know parts of the URL but the URL is linked to the Page which in rendered through the Layout.

So the question becomes: Is there a way to get the page's url paramters in a child component without that child component having something like a `@page` attribute?

What I've tried (but not limited to):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-parameters
- [How to pass parameters to a top-level server-side blazor component from an MVC/Razor page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884875/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-top-level-server-side-blazor-component-from-an-mvc-r)

All these solutions work based on custom interpretation/parsing of the URI. I feel like I've already done that in the page component and should not have to create my own parser of the URI:

```
@page "/project/{name}"

<h3>Details </h3>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string name { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

This page does not know about the NavComponent, the NavComponent is hosted through the Layout and as such I cannot pass the parameter as an attribute to the NavComponent:

```
<MenuItem Title="Home" Icon="fa fa-home" Url="/@name/fun-page"/>  <-- name as retrieved in the page

<div>@technicalName</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string name { get; set; } <-- get from page hosting this component
}
```

To restrict the answer:

1. I understand that I can parse the URI myself (`NavigationManager`) but that's not pretty.
2. I understand I can use application state or session state and save those values, but that gets messy fast and I worry about the complexity.
3. Ideally, I'd like to trigger the same logic as what happens in the page component to parse the URI but in my child component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you've created a Company parent component which can get a route parameter to represent a company ID, the value of which is used to retrieve the company's details that may be displayed in a child component. You may define the parent component like this:

### Company.razor

```
@page "/company"
@page "/company/{ID}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Add this code to the MainLayout component

```
@code{

    public string ID { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // pull out the "ID" parameter from the route data
        object id = null;
        if ((this.Body.Target as RouteView)?.RouteData.RouteValues?.TryGetValue("ID", out id) == true)
        {
            ID = id?.ToString();
        }
       
    }
}
```

Note: The code above extricates the value of the ID parameter from the RouteData, and stores it in the ID property. Now you can do with it, whatever you want... including passing it to the the NavMenu Component if it's necessary there. This is how you can do it:

Add a Component Parameter property to the NavMenu Component, like this:

```
[Parameter]
public string ID { get; set; }
```

And add an ID component parameter attribute to the NavMenu component instance (located at the top of the MainLayout component. It should be now  `<NavMenu  ID="@ID"/>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry the question wasn't clear enough but your answer covers the use-case perfectly. I run into issues; seems like timing issues. The `this.Body.Target` part is sometimes `BlazorTest.App.<>c` which results in the parameter being `null`. Sometimes it is filled though making it really flaky. Is there a class I can `@inject` which contains the `RouteData` instead of having to pass the parameters like this?

Comment: Steve Sanderson, the creator of Blazor, has already mentioned that he was influenced by Harry Potter when creating Blazor, but no mention was made of such magic class that you can inject and get your wishes fulfilled. My code is not flaky. It is robust and does what it is set to do. If you type a url such as `https://localhost:44307/counter`, the ID variable will contain the `null` value, but if you type the url `https://localhost:44307/counter/12`, the ID variable will contain the value `12`.

Comment: Your code should decide what to do with the retrieved value. And as you can see, you can downstream the retrieved value to children component, as for instance, to the NavMenu Component, which is a child component of the MainLayout component.

Comment: Just to clarify, your code is not flaky.

Comment: I fully agree with what you wrote and it should work. I’ve now created 3 projects to test it. 2 work super; the 3e doesn’t. It works if i await a ‘Task.Delay’. Will try and find out why. Will accept the answer in the meantime.

Comment: "It works if i await a ‘Task.Delay’." Show complete code in an answer which you should delete later on.

Comment: The code which is not working is proprietary, am trying to create a version which doesn't work but I seem to not be able to replicate the problem. This is going to take a while. In the mean time I will accept the answer but will remark that combining your answer with @MrC aka Shaun Curtis is probably the right combination.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just cascade the values?

```
@page "/project/{name}"
<CascadingValue Name="ProjectName" Value="@name">
<h3>Details </h3>
<ProjectName/>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

ProjectName.razor

```
<h3>@ProjName</h3>

@code {

    [CascadingParameter(Name ="ProjectName") ] public string? ProjName { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Works like a charm when combined with accepted answer.